# How to update regulatory database used by CRDA in Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. But it has older version of regulatory database (regulatory.bin). I would like to use latest regulatory database that's available @ https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/network/wireless-regdb/wireless-regdb-2015.06.05.tar.gz .

I downloaded above tar ball, untarred it. Then tried checking by running `Regdbdump ./regulatory.bin`. I get below error:

```
Database signature verification failed.
```

Any idea, how do I get around this problem?